# como eu utilizo o for corretamente?

Tags: c, for

eu estou fazendo uma atividade de EP e ele me pediu isso na imagem, mas eu fiquei estacado na parte da sequencia, por que, tipo a sequencia é os numeros de cima é uma sequencia crescende de 1 a infinito, e embaixo são potencias de 2, eu queria saber como posso fazer as potencias de 2 sem a biblioteca math,
tentei um codigo meio de teste, eu também pensei em colocar o valor do for em alguma incognita e usar ela pra multiplicar a equação, mas eu não sei tbm como armazenar o valor de for mas nem rola, então to meio perdido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```c
#include "stdio.h"
int main(void) {
  int t,i=0;
  float p,QuadNum;

  // seleção inicial 
  printf("digite um numero ");
  scanf("%d",&t);
  for( i=0;i<=t;i++){
QuadNum=i;
  }
  p= (1*2*3*4*5)/(QuadNum*i);
  printf(" o valor é  %f =",p);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Para elevar um número ao quadrado é só multiplicar por ele mesmo. Ex: 3² = 3*3, 4² = 4*4

Answer (score 1):

Basta ir multiplicando o denominador por 2.

Veja que há um padrão:

- o primeiro termo é 1 dividido por 2
- o segundo termo é 2 dividido por 4
- o terceire termo é 3 dividido por 8
- ...

Ou seja, a cada novo termo, o numerador aumenta em 1, e o denominador dobra de valor.

Então basta fazer isso:

```
float p = 1, denominador = 1;
int qtd;
printf("Digite a quantidade de termos:");
scanf("%d", &qtd);
for (int i = 1; i <= qtd; i++) {
    denominador *= 2;
    p *= i / denominador;
}
printf("O valor é: %f", p);
```

O numerador é controlado pelo `for`, pois se eu tiver `n` termos, ele varia de 1 a `n` (e é isso que o `for` faz, vai de 1 até a quantidade de termos informada).

Já o denominador começa em 1 e cada iteração ele dobra (é multiplicado por 2).

Tendo o numerador e denominador, basta dividir um pelo outro e multiplicar ao valor atual de `p`.